Online data structure with Avg/Min/Max range requests (massive raw data application)
I have an array of real-time growing data. There is a problem to obtain aggregate parameters (like average, minimum, maximum etc) on a number of consecutive intervals of specified length (the length value can be changed at any time) as fast as possible. The length change means that I have to recalculate all the parameters according to that new length value.
Example of two length values (L = 3 and 5, same starting point):

Segment tree seems good for range requests but looks like it is only for static data (appending new data causes tree rebuilding what can be quite slow on massive data). Is there any modifications of Segment tree or other structures with reasonable memory overhead and similar to Segment tree complexity (log N)?
Thanks.

Maybe this question would be better suited at the Computer Science Stack Exchange? https://cs.stackexchange.com/ That being said, if I'm not mistaken the "tree rebuilding" should not be such a big issue, as appending (or changing a value) usually only requires the parent nodes of the tree to be updated, and only rebuild the tree when a new level needs to be added.

@Lucero Probably it is but I couldn't move it (and even couldn't find how to choose appropriate topic domain). Sorry.
As for "tree rebuilding" - it means filling the structure from scratch after appending new value (no value updates required). At least this implementation (Arbitrary sized array chapter) seems to be quite efficient (as it stores whole tree in sole array and uses very simple indexing) but doesn't provide any opportunity to append values without the "rebuilding".

If you look at the implementation you linked, look at the image in the Arbitrary sized array section. It shows 5 levels and 6 empty spots, if the array were sized as power of two. Now when you think about appending (e.g. filling the next empty spot), this will only lead to changes in 4 existing parent spots, and not require a tree rebuild.

Or to express it differently, whenever an empty spot is available, appending actually requires the same tree updates to be done as when updating an existing value.

@Lucero Nope, it is not that simple. I have prepared a picture describing what changes have to be done if you simply added one value. https://imgur.com/a/GwDyH8k As you can see, entire array is changed. So if you have 1kk array, even one addition requires 2kk updates.

Note that I wrote "...if the array were sized as power of two". Look at the following image with 3 append steps: https://i.postimg.cc/sx2zWcsy/Segment-Tree-Append.png - A "max" Segment Tree as if it were for 16 values, but with some empty slots, which allow for update-like append. When all slots are full, I first reallocate a new array of size 63 and rebuild the Segment tree, which gives again 16 free slots to fill efficiently. Note that I could use a struct with Avg/Max/Min fields for each array index, and update these all at once, instead of three distinct Segment Trees.

As for rebuilding, the rebuild in that case is cheap since only 1 value needs to be computed, all the rest is just copying from the old array with varying offsets. See image: https://i.postimg.cc/J03nCBkv/Segment-Tree-Resize.png As for memory usage, it remains linear, array size is up to 4 times the data size (when half of it are empty slots just after resizing). It would also be possible, of course, to pre-allocate a suitable size in advance,

@Lucero Thanks for your explanation, I got your point. But I am not sure if +2N memory size and quite decent amount of copying is a good tradeoff. Now I implemented a storage based on std vector of vectors. Actually, it looks very similar under the hood (reserved memory size and copy during vector resize) but at least it is a part of std lib so no need to worry about efficient implementation. However I have doubts about memory fragmentation after a long period of data growth.
